# github copilot labs error when generating test

Tags: chai, github-copilot

He throws me this error when, once I generate the tests with github copilot, I give him to run test, to test them, in the same copilot.

```
Error running test: Error: Unable to find chai; please install it in your project or globally.
    (Underlying error: Cannot find module 'chai'
    Require stack:
    - c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-labs-0.10.726\dist\extension.js
    - c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
    - c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
    - c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
    - )
```

He installed chai globally, but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if the local chai installation is available in the project?
The installation manual for chai is available [here](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/installation/#nodejs).
You can check if chai is installed with those [demo examples](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).